# Jackson object to string failing without an exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm using Spring Boot Websockets and have been trying to convert an object to a JSON string.

If I do this in a main method it converts to JSON string as expected but when done inside the Spring Boot Websocket endpoint it stops anything from progressing but throws no exceptions.

I'm using Corretto 17.0.1.

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Room(0, "Room Name")));
        // Outputs "{"id":0,"name":"Room Name","bluePlayerId":null,"redPlayerId":null,"board":{"blueScore":0,"redScore":0,"bluePiecesInPlay":3,"redPiecesInPlay":3,"state":31,"bluePieces":42,"redPieces":44040192,"allPieces":44040234}}" as expected. 
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Spring Boot WebSocket endpoint**

This just outputs "generating" and doesn't print anything else. When debugging it just skips out of it and completes the test.

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@MessageMapping("/welcome/{roomName}")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public String greeting(@DestinationVariable String roomName) {
    System.out.println("Generating");

    try {
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Room(0, "Room Name")));
        System.out.println("Complete");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Caught exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Hello!";
}
```

**Gradle**

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.5.6'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.6'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.0'
}
```

**Logs (TRACE)**

```
Generating
2021-11-13 10:35:07.430 TRACE 9204 --- [    Test worker] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : afterTestClass(): class [com.app.cairnserver.controller.RoomControllerTest]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.431 DEBUG 9204 --- [    Test worker] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Retrieved ApplicationContext [2118984327] from cache with key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@76ba13c testClass = RoomControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.app.cairnserver.CairnServerApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@33308786, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@561868a0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@21a21c64, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@531f4093, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@3568f9d2, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@1e6454ec], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.431 DEBUG 9204 --- [    Test worker] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@197ce367 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 11, missCount = 1]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.432 DEBUG 9204 --- [    Test worker] tractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener : After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@274872f8 testClass = RoomControllerTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@76ba13c testClass = RoomControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.app.cairnserver.CairnServerApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@33308786, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@561868a0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@21a21c64, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@531f4093, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@3568f9d2, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@1e6454ec], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> false, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
2021-11-13 10:35:07.440 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
2021-11-13 10:35:07.440 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7e4d2287, started on Sat Nov 13 10:35:03 GMT 2021
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'simpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'simpleBrokerMessageHandler'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userDestinationMessageHandler'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'webServerGracefulShutdown'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'webServerStartStop'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.441 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2021-11-13 10:35:07.442 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' of type [org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerMapping] to stop
2021-11-13 10:35:07.442 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' completed its stop procedure
2021-11-13 10:35:07.442 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' of type [org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler] to stop
2021-11-13 10:35:07.442 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.ExecutorSubscribableChannel      : clientOutboundChannel removed SubProtocolWebSocketHandler[StompSubProtocolHandler[v10.stomp, v11.stomp, v12.stomp]]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.442 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Closing SockJS session de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1 with CloseStatus[code=1001, reason=null]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.442 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Writing SockJsFrame content='c[1001,""]'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.442 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.w.s.adapter.NativeWebSocketSession   : Sending TextMessage payload=[c[1001,""]], byteCount=10, last=true], StandardWebSocketSession[id=31cd4a31-05d6-9c7e-cd3a-6653dfe98f53, uri=ws://localhost:57909/chess-websocket/433/de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1/websocket]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Cancelling heartbeat in session de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.w.s.adapter.NativeWebSocketSession   : Closing StandardWebSocketSession[id=31cd4a31-05d6-9c7e-cd3a-6653dfe98f53, uri=ws://localhost:57909/chess-websocket/433/de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1/websocket]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [lient-AsyncIO-8] o.s.w.s.s.c.WebSocketClientSockJsSession : Processing SockJS close frame with CloseStatus[code=1001, reason=] in WebSocketClientSockJsSession[id='de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1, url=ws://localhost:57909/chess-websocket]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [lient-AsyncIO-8] o.s.w.s.adapter.NativeWebSocketSession   : Closing StandardWebSocketSession[id=2b84c8e4-9985-7077-6111-4ecafbe6fbe1, uri=null]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [lient-AsyncIO-8] o.s.w.s.s.c.WebSocketClientSockJsSession : Transport closed with CloseStatus[code=1001, reason=] in WebSocketClientSockJsSession[id='de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1, url=ws://localhost:57909/chess-websocket]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [lient-AsyncIO-8] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : WebSocketClientSockJsSession[id='de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1, url=ws://localhost:57909/chess-websocket] closed with CloseStatus[code=1001, reason=]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1] closed with CloseStatus[code=1001, reason=null]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [lient-AsyncIO-8] o.s.m.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession     : Connection closed in session id=397d262e-13e0-8023-d8da-c88950c1d12f
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : Clearing session de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [lient-AsyncIO-8] o.s.w.s.s.c.WebSocketClientSockJsSession : Closing session with CloseStatus[code=1000, reason=null] in WebSocketClientSockJsSession[id='de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1, url=ws://localhost:57909/chess-websocket]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.443 DEBUG 9204 --- [lient-AsyncIO-8] o.s.w.s.s.c.WebSocketClientSockJsSession : Ignoring close (already closing or closed): current state CLOSED
2021-11-13 10:35:07.444 DEBUG 9204 --- [boundChannel-11] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing DISCONNECT session=de878120ded742a78ba92f16b12ba9e1
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' completed its stop procedure
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean 'simpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler' of type [org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler] to stop
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.ExecutorSubscribableChannel      : clientInboundChannel removed WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler[prefixes=[/app/]]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean 'simpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler' completed its stop procedure
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean 'simpleBrokerMessageHandler' of type [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler] to stop
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445  INFO 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Stopping...
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445  INFO 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=false, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry@22048bd6]]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.ExecutorSubscribableChannel      : clientInboundChannel removed SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry@22048bd6]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.ExecutorSubscribableChannel      : brokerChannel removed SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry@22048bd6]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445  INFO 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Stopped.
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean 'simpleBrokerMessageHandler' completed its stop procedure
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean 'userDestinationMessageHandler' of type [org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.UserDestinationMessageHandler] to stop
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.ExecutorSubscribableChannel      : clientInboundChannel removed UserDestinationMessageHandler[DefaultUserDestinationResolver[prefix=/user/]]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.ExecutorSubscribableChannel      : brokerChannel removed UserDestinationMessageHandler[DefaultUserDestinationResolver[prefix=/user/]]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean 'userDestinationMessageHandler' completed its stop procedure
2021-11-13 10:35:07.445 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean 'webServerGracefulShutdown' of type [org.springframework.boot.web.context.WebServerGracefulShutdownLifecycle] to stop
2021-11-13 10:35:07.446 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean 'webServerGracefulShutdown' completed its stop procedure
2021-11-13 10:35:07.447 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483646
2021-11-13 10:35:07.447 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean 'webServerStartStop' of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle] to stop
2021-11-13 10:35:07.475 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean 'webServerStartStop' completed its stop procedure
2021-11-13 10:35:07.475 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3bd3d05e: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor$SpyPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer$TestRestTemplateRegistrar,cairnServerApplication,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory,webSocketConfig,roomController,boardService,roomService,org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration,stompWebSocketHandlerMapping,subProtocolWebSocketHandler,webSocketScopeConfigurer,webSocketMessageBrokerStats,clientInboundChannel,clientInboundChannelExecutor,clientOutboundChannel,clientOutboundChannelExecutor,brokerChannel,brokerChannelExecutor,simpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler,simpleBrokerMessageHandler,stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler,userDestinationMessageHandler,userRegistryMessageHandler,messageBrokerTaskScheduler,brokerMessagingTemplate,brokerMessageConverter,userDestinationResolver,userRegistry,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration,propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration$TomcatWebSocketConfiguration,websocketServletWebServerCustomizer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat,tomcatServletWebServerFactory,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration,servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer,tomcatServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer,org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinderFactory,org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinder,org.springframework.boot.context.properties.BoundConfigurationProperties,org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.methodValidationExcludeFilter,server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties,webServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor,errorPageRegistrarBeanPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration,dispatcherServlet,spring.mvc-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration,dispatcherServletRegistration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration,taskExecutorBuilder,spring.task.execution-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration,error,beanNameViewResolver,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$DefaultErrorViewResolverConfiguration,conventionErrorViewResolver,spring.web-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebProperties,spring.resources-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration,errorAttributes,basicErrorController,errorPageCustomizer,preserveErrorControllerTargetClassPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,requestMappingHandlerMapping,welcomePageHandlerMapping,localeResolver,themeResolver,flashMapManager,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,mvcContentNegotiationManager,mvcPatternParser,mvcUrlPathHelper,mvcPathMatcher,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,routerFunctionMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,mvcResourceUrlProvider,defaultServletHandlerMapping,handlerFunctionAdapter,mvcUriComponentsContributor,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,mvcViewResolver,mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector,viewNameTranslator,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter,defaultViewResolver,viewResolver,requestContextFilter,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration,formContentFilter,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration$ClassProxyingConfiguration,forceAutoProxyCreatorToUseClassProxying,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration,applicationAvailability,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration,standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer,spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration,jacksonObjectMapperBuilder,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration,parameterNamesModule,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration,jacksonObjectMapper,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration,jsonComponentModule,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleAutoConfiguration,lifecycleProcessor,spring.lifecycle-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration,stringHttpMessageConverter,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration,mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration,messageConverters,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration,spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration,spring.sql.init-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationProperties,org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer$DependsOnDatabaseInitializationPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration,scheduledBeanLazyInitializationExcludeFilter,taskSchedulerBuilder,spring.task.scheduling-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration,restTemplateBuilderConfigurer,restTemplateBuilder,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration,tomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration,characterEncodingFilter,localeCharsetMappingsCustomizer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MultipartAutoConfiguration,multipartConfigElement,multipartResolver,spring.servlet.multipart-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MultipartProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration$WebSocketMessageConverterConfiguration,eagerStompWebSocketHandlerMapping,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator]; root of factory hierarchy
2021-11-13 10:35:07.475 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'mvcResourceUrlProvider': [requestMappingHandlerMapping, welcomePageHandlerMapping, viewControllerHandlerMapping, beanNameHandlerMapping, routerFunctionMapping, resourceHandlerMapping]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.476 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'userRegistry': [userDestinationResolver, userRegistryMessageHandler]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.476 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'userDestinationResolver': [userDestinationMessageHandler, stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler, simpleBrokerMessageHandler]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.476 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'userDestinationMessageHandler': [stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.476 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler': [webSocketMessageBrokerStats]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.476 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler': [stompWebSocketHandlerMapping]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.476 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.476 DEBUG 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
2021-11-13 10:35:07.476 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'brokerChannelExecutor': [brokerChannel]
2021-11-13 10:35:07.477 TRACE 9204 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'brokerChannel': [brokerMessagingTemplate]
Complete
```

One thought is this could be due to a library not supporting Java 17 although I couldn't find anything about it.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Enable debug logs on Spring and see what's happening.

Comment: You should inject the ObjectMapper bean provided by Spring, not create a new instance of your own.

Comment: @JamesJithin I've enabled the logs and I'm still not sure what is happening. I've added them to my question. What doesn't make sense to me is that the Java code looks fine to me? If the print line executes then it doesn't matter what the object mapper returns, there should still be a line somewhere in my logs?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I've changed to injecting the ObjectMapper as you mentioned. It doesn't change anything. 
I don't know what's diffierent but as of this morning the same code is now printing `complete` so it is continuing past the objectmapper section. It still doesn't make sense why nothing is printed for the objectmapper line though.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what is causing this. The test is closing the server before the ObjectMapper has converted the object into JSON.

To fix this I used a `BlockingQueue` in my test and polled for 1 second after sending the message.

```
BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1);

stompSession.subscribe("/topic/greetings", new StompFrameHandler() {

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + payload);

    }
});

stompSession.send("/app/welcome/test", "Mike");
blockingQueue.poll(1, SECONDS);
```